# How to hash password in format with respect to asp.net identity core v2.2.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

So I want to hash the password with same algorithm  followed in asp.net core identity v2.2.1 but hash generated by my code is completely different from the hash generated by  asp.net core identity v2.2.1

for example hash for 12345678 is

AGhTgD39ivyJtpe0pKALKjE+HwO4FSr8N08yVM/+BslSVEXWpDZj9CC0BVY5V8Xrdw==

but hash generated by my code

ADwuhmrych2Y2OQpFsSRNjLkFWMnj++Czyp0NFMe7oZBU9noN5B4bXyopljBNLs7mQ==

I need a hash function which generate the hash in same format any help is appreciated

```
public  string HashPwd(string password)
        {
             int Pbkdf2IterCount = 1000; // default for Rfc2898DeriveBytes
             int Pbkdf2SubkeyLength = 256 / 8; // 256 bits
             int SaltSize = 128 / 8;

            if (password == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("password");
            }

            // Produce a version 0 (see comment above) text hash.
            byte[] salt;
            byte[] subkey;
            using (var deriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, SaltSize, Pbkdf2IterCount))
            {
                salt = deriveBytes.Salt;
                subkey = deriveBytes.GetBytes(Pbkdf2SubkeyLength);
            }

            var outputBytes = new byte[1 + SaltSize + Pbkdf2SubkeyLength];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, 0, outputBytes, 1, SaltSize);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(subkey, 0, outputBytes, 1 + SaltSize, Pbkdf2SubkeyLength);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(outputBytes);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each hashed password has a random salt. You are using Rfc2898DeriveBytes function which generates a hash and a salt. The salt and hash(salt is prepended to the hash ) link together and then encode to hashed password.

When verify the password , salt will be extracted from the stored hashed password ,use the Rfc2898DeriveBytes function to create the hash with salt , compare the hash with stored one .

So that each time you hash the same password you will get different hashed passwords .